# How does the pronunciation change in verbs that end with "‑e" or "‑ie" for their "‑ing" forms?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, ing, inflectional-morphology

How do you pronounce the *‑ing* forms of verbs that originally end with *-e* or *‑ie*?

Although the rules for writing such verbs that end with *‑e* or *‑ie* are сlear:

- make > making (take off "-e" + "‑ing")
- die > dying (take off "‑ie" + "‑ying")

Nonetheless, the rules for their pronunciation are not clear to me like those for their spellings are.

How do you pronounce a final *‑e* and *‑ie* when you add an *‑ing* to it in these verbs?

Comment: I'm feeling a bit ***stymied*** here. What exactly are you asking? I'm not wild about the orthography myself, but you can't really argue with the dictionary: [**stymy**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stymy) *Past participle: **stymied** Gerund: **stymying***. Admittedly, we usually spell the base form [***stymie***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stymie), but that simply can't work with the ***ing*** suffix.

Comment: Variously related including some probable duplicates: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/139349 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/390330 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/184945 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/60852 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/30679 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/244280 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/292342 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/76666 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/38524 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/107157

Comment: @FumbleFingers what does mean "stymy"? There is no such word. Why are you talking about "stymied". It is not a verb, but a past participle.

Comment: Your 100-rep start implies you know how SO sites work, so you should have realised that [**stymy**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stymy) in my first comment was *a link to a dictionary definition*. Which by implication means *there is such a word* - even though (as I pointed out before) *we usually spell it **stymie***.

Comment: @tchrist♦: I'm impressed with the range of "related" posts you came up with (bit dubious about the ***whinge/whine*** one though! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Depends whether you’re [whingeing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stymy) about it. :)

Comment: @tchrist: I did find one written instance of [*...political compulsions have thus **stymyed** any major progress...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=o1qPAAAAMAAJ&q=%22stymyed%22&dq=%22stymyed%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y), but I don't think it's even worth looking for anyone brave/daft enough to have floated ***stymieing*** (or even ***stymiing***, which at least could call on ***skiing*** for orthographic support! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, I did an error: not `die ->dying (take off "-ie" + ing)`, but `die ->dying (take off "-ie" + ` **ying**)`

Comment: Are you simply trying to figure out some "rule" that allows you to "know" how to change the spelling of the base form of a verb when forming its regular *-ing* inflection without having to look it up? I don't see anything here about grammar, just writing. Or are you asking not about the writing but about the pronunciation? All *-ing* inflections are perfectly phonologically regular.

Comment: @tchrist This question is not about writting, this question is only about pronunciation (transcription).

Comment: I've rewritten the question for clarity. Transcription is not related to pronunciation; it's when you convert what is said into writing. You seem to be asking how to pronounce what is written, which is something else again. Moreover, letters like *-e* and *-ie* are not pronounced in any meaningful way in English, because English spelling is not meant to represent English pronunciation in any direct, one-to-one way. You have to learn the spelling and pronunciation of each word completely separately, and each has its own long history.

Comment: @tchrist So, if I known transcription of a verb (infinitive), that ends with -e or ‑ie , I cannot find out transcription of it's -ing form (without dictionary)?

Comment: @Тарас Please don't using the word *transcription* to mean *pronunciation*: that is NOT what the word means. The key point here is that every *-ing* verb sounds exactly like the original verb does but with an extra /ɪŋ/ added to the end of it. The spelling does not matter at all; remember, this is English!

Answer (score 3):

The pronunciation of the *-ing* form of the verbs *die* and *make* is ***completely regular***.

In IPA, *make* is /meɪk/.
*Making* is /ˈmeɪ·kɪŋ/.

In IPA, *dye* is /dɑɪ/.
*Dying* is /ˈdɑɪ·ɪŋ/.

The 'e' on the end of these words is not pronounced, and to make the *-ing* form, you just add /ɪŋ/ to the pronunciation.

There is only one class of verbs I can think of that might be considered irregular — those verbs whose pronunciations end with /-əl/ or /-ər/. Here, you can optionally remove the schwa /ə/.

For example, *table* is pronounced /ˈteɪ·bəl/.
*Tabling* is pronounced /ˈteɪ·bəl·ɪŋ/ *or* /ˈteɪ·blɪŋ/.

Comment: So, when a verb ends with -e or -ie, "-e" or "-ie" are unvoiced?

Comment: @Тарас [You cannot use spelling to correctly infer the pronunciation of an arbitrary word in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/pronunciation-vs-spelling/info). Please don't try.  However the base verb is pronounced, the *-ing* version is pronounced exactly that same way with an extra /ɪŋ/ at the end of it. The spelling never matters at all!

Comment: Also, in British English, the consonant /r/ is not present in verb forms like *dares, fires, stores* but is present in *daring, firing, storing*; for many speakers, it also might be present in *awing.* But this is not really irregular.

Comment: As pointed out in [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184945/) to what may be a duplicate, because the final ***e*** in ***karaoke*** represents a vowel in the pronunciation (unlike that in, say ***make***), this leads to ***karaokeing***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: similarly *ante* and *anteing*.

Comment: @Peter: Eeek! After noting that [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anteing) give both ***anted*** and ***anteed*** for pp (I assume the *pronunciation* is constant), I made a little side bet with myself as to which version would be more common in actual written/published sources. But I'm such a lousy gambler I even lost to myself - I bet on [he anteed up](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+anteed+up%22) (24 hits), but lost to [he anted up](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+anted+up%22) (224), notwithstanding Neil Coffey's advice in above linked answer.